# Construction from many sets

Tags: algorithm, combinations, permutation

I have four sets:

```
A={a,b,c}, B={d,e}, C={c,d}, D={a,b,c,e}
```

I want to search the sequence of sets that give me: `a b c d`

Example: the sequence `A A A C` can give me `a b c d` because "a" is an element of A, "b" is an element of A, "c" is an element of A and "d" is an element of C.

The same thing for : D A C B, etc.

I want an algorithm to enumerate all sequences possibles or a mathematical method to find the sequences.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some hints on writing a good-quality question.

Comment: I don't see any graph here.  Also you don't say whether the sequence of input letters is significant (is the input abcd the same as e.g. dbac, or not?)  Either way, first build an index that maps each letter to the list of sets that contain it (e.g. "a" maps to {A, D}).  Now just go through each letter recursively: all solutions for the first i letters can be found by taking the list of solutions to the first i-1 letters, and then appending each of the sets containing the ith letter to the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really come up with some code of your own and then ask specific questions about problems with it. But it's interesting, so I'll share some thoughts.

You want `a b c d`.

```
a can come from A, D
b can come from A, D
c can come from A, C, D
d can come from B, C
```

So the problem reduces to finding all of the 2*2*3*2=24 ways to combine those options.

One way is recursion with backtracking. Build it from left to right, output when you have a complete set. Like the 8 queens problem, but much simpler since everything is independent.

Another way is to count the integers and map them into a mixed-base system. First digit base 2, then 2, 3, 2. So 0 becomes AAAB, 1 is AAAC, 2 is AACB, etc. 23 is DDDC and 24 needs five digits so you stop there.

Comment: thanks a lot Tom Zych this the first thought I had in mind